# Does Vayne's Tumble (Q) damage affect Trinity Force?

Tags: league-of-legends

Yesterday we saw Doublelift build a Trinity Force on Vayne.

However, I asked myself a few questions, since I have never really played Vayne:

1. Does her Q proc Spellblade? (I highly assume YES)
2. Does her Q affect Trinity Force bonus damage?

Example (armor calculation ignored)

1. We have 100 AD and maxed Q.
2. Our next attack after we Q (without TF) would deal 150 AD (100 * 1.50)
3. Our next attack after we Q (with TF) would deal 450 AD ((100 * 1.50) * 3.00)

The * 3.00 comes form the 200% bonus damage TF grants after a spell is cast.
100% + 200% = 300%

**Am I missing or miscalculating something here?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To your first question: **Yes it does trigger the spellblade effect**.

For your second question:

**No, it does not affect spellblade!** You are misunderstanding how Trinity Force (or spellblades in general) works.

Trinity force will give you 200% of your **Base AD** as bonus damage. The bonus damage cannot be increased through Items, Ablities or Runes/Masteries. The only thing that actually works is **Base AD**. This means for a level 18 Vayne with 109 base damage TF will exactly deal 218 Physical bonus damage. It does not benefit from crit or spells and is simply added to the damage you'd deal anyways.

So basically what would happen:

If you have a fully maxed Q and 200 AD with 100 Base AD You would deal:

200/400 (basic attack/crit) + 
200 x 0.5 (bonus damage from tumble) + 
100 * 2 (bonus damage from TF)

**500** damage with a normal Attack or **700** with a crit since both the Tumble  and the spellblade bonus damage don't benefit from crit.

Comment: Damnit, you were faster. ._. Anyways, i think that the last mastery in the offense tree increases the dmg trinity deals.

Comment: you literally answer every LoL question, you should work for them rito pls

Comment: @RandomDisplayName as what :D

Comment: @PhilippSander currently thinking the same thing :D customer support isn't my favorite thing to do. On Arqade there are quality questions, but the LoL forums are full of 13 years old kids that ask questions.

Comment: @Jutschge should i be offended?! xD I'm not 13 :-P. but if you talk about the forums you're damn right... and those how aren't 13 flame the 13 year olds.

Comment: @PhilippSander fixed comment ;)

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes
2. No. Because the passive is:

   Unique Passive - Spellblade: After using an ability, your next basic attack deals 200% base AD bonus physical damage. (1.5 second cooldown).

Trinity doesn't increase the dmg you deal, it deals bonus dmg the more AD you have (that's why the passive says **bonus physical damage**). So the calculation is:

```
(100 * 1.50) + (100 * 2) = 350
```

Comment: +1 actually you were faster :O but i like the other explanation more.