# Nidalee Takedown Damage

Tags: league-of-legends

Was playing Nidalee and built trinity force as usual, this got me thinking. How is the damage for 'Takedown' calculated with a Tri-force proc. For example, if the Tri-force spellblade damage is taken into account first, the 'Takedown' will deal more execute damage, however if the execute damage is calculated first then the ability will do less damage.

My question may seem a little confusing. What I'm basically asking is:
What damage applies first when Nidalee uses takedown with a tri-force proc? (The spellblade damage, or the takedown damage?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Vayne's Tumble (Q) damage affect Trinity Force?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/183692/does-vaynes-tumble-q-damage-affect-trinity-force)

Comment: @PhilippSander Thought the same at first but I think it's more about the timing of the item rather than about the Damage.

Comment: @PhilippSander yea, i read the vayne question before posting this and although similar they are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Damage from trinity force is simply added to your Takedown damage. This basically means that the damage from trinity force is applied at exactly the same time as your takedown (you will see one damage number) but it has the effect as if it was applied **after** your Q.

So you won't gain the lowlife based percentage bonus damage from a trinity force but you will still get a nice burst boost which is why Trinity force is still a really decent item on AD/Bruiser Nidalee (and of course the other stats).